# Null & False in PHP

Tags: php, null

I came across this question. What am I missing?

```
function ninja($x, $y, $z) 
{

     if ($y != $z && $x == $y && $x == $z) {
        return "Yes";   
      }

    return "No";    
}
```

**For what values of $x, $y, $z will this function return "Yes" ?**

Comment: Here's a good link about "tautologies" (the logical expression is always 'true') and "contradictions" (always 'false'): http://people.hofstra.edu/stefan_waner/realworld/logic/logic2.html

Answer (score 3):

Since `==` and `!=` allow type juggling, various combinations of values will allow the function to return `Yes`. One version is

```
function ninja($x, $y, $z) {
    if ($y != $z && $x == $y && $x == $z) {
        return "Yes";
    }

    return "No";
}

echo ninja(0, 'a', 'b');
```

Since non numeric strings - when compared to and type juggled to an integer - have the value 0, the strange result is;

```
* $x == $y    (0 == 'a')
* $x == $z    (0 == 'b')
* $y != $z    ('a' != 'b') (both are strings, so no type juggling)
```

The documentation of [comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) will give some more type juggling ideas, the short version is that there are probably more combinations, but they're not always obvious. Reading it gives good motivation to learn to use `===` and `!==` though :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Your logic:-

```
if ($y != $z && $x == $y && $x == $z)
```

so here

```
1. $y != $z
2. $x == $y
3. $x == $z
```

if I consider point 2 and 3 then

```
i. $x == $y
ii. $x == $z this means $y == $z
```

But You have a condition  **$y != $z**

So Your above **if()** condition will never be true. It always return false.

Comment: Mathematically, but not in PHP. ii. is not correct for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This will return true.

```
ninja(0, false, 'a');
```

One of the quirks of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

if you take

```
$x=0;
$y='z'; #only alphabet character 
$z='x'; #only alphabet character
```

Because PHP is [loosely-typed] language you can always cast string to number by adding a zero to it. So you have to take `$x` value is always 0.